# Parsing JSON object within a JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'm trying to get a bit of javascript working to pull back a currency conversion.

Using the API from fixer.io, I'm requesting 
http://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols=USD&base=GBP

I get an object back, but I don't know how to drill down to the currency value I need.

My code so far:

```
function GetMarketRate() {

    var url = 'http://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols=_CURR&base=GBP'.replace("_CURR", "@Model.CurrencyId");

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);

    xhr.onload = function () {
        var res = window.JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        //Drill down

    };

    xhr.onerror = function () {
        //Process error
    };

    xhr.send();

};
```

I'm using MVC and Razor to amend the URL to get the Currency.
I will then take the decimal value and insert it into an inline div as the page loads.

The only problem I have is actually getting to that value.
My API request is such that it will only ever pull back one value - don't know if that helps things.

Comment: what does `console.log(res);` output?

Comment: Since we don't know how the JSON is organised, we can't tell you (short of writing a complete guide to how to access object properties and loop over data in JS).

Comment: Using `res.rates.USD` doesn't work?

Comment: console.log(res) returns: Object {base: "GBP", date: "2015-06-18", rates: Object}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned object looks like:

```
{"base":"GBP","date":"2015-06-18","rates":{"USD":1.5912}}
```

So you should be able to use:

```
res.rates.USD // 1.5912
```

Comment: I need to be able to use @Model.CurrencyId in Razor to define the currency. How do I code it to include this?

Comment: This has actually helped alot. I can use res.rates.@Model.CurrencyId which gets me what I need. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Razor but as long as it preprocesses the code then it sounds like it should work.

Comment: Razor is an ASP.NET view engine, long story short, yes it preprocesses the page before returning the response to the browser.